# How to locate a particular image in watir?

Tags: ruby, selenium, automation, watir-webdriver

```
[1] pry(main)> require 'watir-webdriver'
=> true
[2] pry(main)> browser = Watir::Browser.new
=> #<Watir::Browser:0x61b0b0e094c1512a url="about:blank" title="">
[3] pry(main)> browser.goto 'm.racingnetwork.com.au'
=> "http://m.racingnetwork.com.au/"
[4] pry(main)> browser.frames.size
=> 0
[5] pry(main)> browser.imgs.size
=> 12
[6] pry(main)> x = browser.imgs[0].src
=> "http://m.racingnetwork.com.au/mobile-telstra-racingnetwork-production/theme/img/bpBannerSportLogo_170.png"
[7] pry(main)> browser.img(:src, x).exist?
=> false
[8] pry(main)> browser.img(:src, /mobile/).exist?
=> false
[9] pry(main)> browwer.img.exist?
=> true
[10] pry(main)> browser.img.id
=> ""
```

Why can't I access that image, do I have some syntax error in my locator?

Unfortunately I don't have any better locators like element ids in this case.  The last time I had a problem with Watir not being able to find elements, it was due to frames, but here we aren't in any frames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I try to do it, and don't find. By doing exactly the same thing in another website, it works.

Start of your page :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.0//EN" "http://www.wapforum.org/DTD/xhtml-mobile10.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
```

Start of mine to compare:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="fr" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Blog">
```

The only difference I see is the XML : the page you are playing with is in XML, you should verify that you don't need to parse XML instead of classic HTML.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see, the HTML of the first image looks like this:

```
<img class="greendot-logo" src="/mobile-telstra-racingnetwork-production/theme/img/bpBannerSportLogo_465.png" alt="" height="80" width="232">
```

You have this:

```
> browser.img(:src, /mobile/).exist?
=> false
```

But I get this:

```
> browser.img(:src, /mobile/).exist?
=> true
```

So, try this:

```
> browser.img(:src => "/mobile-telstra-racingnetwork-production/theme/img/bpBannerSportLogo_465.png").exists?
=> true
```

Comment: I get false for the last one aswell  :(  
I'm on `Watir::VERSION` 0.6.3 and `ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22 revision 39386) [x86_64-linux]`, latest version of firefox and all gems updated ..

Comment: Watir 0.6.3?! What do you get when you type this into command line? `gem list watir`

Comment: it says `*** LOCAL GEMS *** watir-webdriver (0.6.3)`

Comment: Hi, today I've upgraded to 0.6.4 and retried, but there was no change in behaviour from what's already shown in my original post.

Comment: Could you advise what versions you are using, maybe I can make my problem resolved by changing to the same versions?

Comment: I am using the latest watir-webdriver, 0.6.4.

Comment: Can't reproduce too. Watir-webdriver 0.6.4 and Firefox 18.0.1. What @Zeljko does works for me fine.